# React native cli\build\bin.js can not resolved

Tags: android, react-native

I can run my rn project without error.I just create another for test something with

```
react-native init testapp
```

and then opened with vs code , run this command as  usual

```
react-native run-android --no-jetifier
```

it runs the code in emulator.But now it gives error in new project like that.

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 971 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\sampleuser\Desktop\samplee\testapp\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\sampleuser\Desktop\samplee\testapp\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\sampleuser\Desktop\samplee\testapp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 195

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1033  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\sampleuser\Desktop\samplee\testapp\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1030:15)    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 1s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

also i tryed

```
npx react-native run-android

Also tryed
uninstall and reinstall nodemodules
Cold start Emulator
Update android sdk
Still gives same error
```

Also tryed to downgrade version

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.0",
    "react-native": "0.60.0",
```

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\sampleuser\Desktop\samplee\testapp\android\app\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Your project path contains non-ASCII characters. This will most likely cause the build to fail on Windows. Please move your project to a different directory. See http://b.android.com/95744 for details. This warning can be disabled by adding the line 'android.overridePathCheck=true' to gradle.properties file in the project directory.
```

```
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, \node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, \node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.
```

```
react-native --version
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.63.2
```

Comment: I can't run my code

Comment: I tryed it says "error: unknown option `--stacktrace'" also "error: unknown option `--info'"

Comment: Am I asking something wrong or wrong way

Answer (score 0):

You didn't enter your project file with "cd" command.You must run your command in your project file.That's why it gives this error.The solution is gonna be in these following steps.

1. When you initiliaze your project with command "npx react-native init testapp", you need to start metro bundler.[(You can find the details about Metro)](https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/concepts/) Before you start metro bundler,You should write down "cd testapp/" command in VS terminal.This will get in your project file.Than,write command which is gonna start metro "npx react-native start".
2. Secondly,let metro run in its own terminal.Open a new terminal inside your react native project folder.Get into your file again in this terminal too with "cd testapp/".

3.Finally,run your emulator from Android studio.And write "npx react-native run-android" command.[(You can go look for how AVD starts with Android Stuido in this link)](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

Additionally,[(VS code screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAK6i.png)